# Using Qt 5.3 QML Video on target getting Error: "Resource not Found" code works on host system both are Linux

Tags: qt, qml, gstreamer

```
thurberdog [2:23 PM]
Have video running on host system, but not embedded arm imx6 target getting classic error out of gstreamer which is the correct 0.10 for Qt 5.3 and the multimedia flag is set in the project file. First the error then the code QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QEglFSImx6Hooks will set environment variable FB_MULTI_BUFFER=2 to enable double buffering and vsync.
If this is not desired, you can override this via: export QT_EGLFS_IMX6_NO_FB_MULTI_BUFFER=1
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/Videos/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:///home/Videos/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:~///Projects/Slider1/video/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:~///Projects/Slider1/video/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:~///Projects/Slider1/video/big_buck_bunny_1080p_stero.avi"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:~///Projects/Slider1/video/big_buck_bunny_1080p_stero.avi"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.flv"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.flv"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mkv"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mkv"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4"
Error: "Resource not found."
Timeout waiting for reply from server.
files exist on target
here QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QEglFSImx6Hooks will set environment variable FB_MULTI_BUFFER=2 to enable double buffering and vsync.
If this is not desired, you can override this via: export QT_EGLFS_IMX6_NO_FB_MULTI_BUFFER=1
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/Videos/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:///home/Videos/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:~///Projects/Slider1/video/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:~///Projects/Slider1/video/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:~///Projects/Slider1/video/big_buck_bunny_1080p_stero.avi"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:~///Projects/Slider1/video/big_buck_bunny_1080p_stero.avi"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.flv"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.flv"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mkv"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mkv"
GStreamer; Unable to pause - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4"
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4"
Error: "Resource not found."
Timeout waiting for reply from server.
```

Any clues or guesses welcome, I am able to play audio files without issue

Comment: Video {
       id: video
       width: 800
       height: 800
       autoLoad: true
       source: "file:///home/Videos/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
   }

Comment: Component.onCompleted: {
       video.play()
       video.source = "file:///Projects/Slider1/video/big_buck_bunny_1080p_h264.mov"
       video.play()
       video.source = "file:///Projects/Slider1/video/big_buck_bunny_1080p_stero.avi"
       video.play()
       video.source = "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.flv"
       video.play()
       video.source = "file:///home/reach/Projects/Slider1/video/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mkv"
       video.play()
   }

Comment: Question also posted in slack QtMob #embedded

Answer (score 0):

Simple GStreamer was not finding video file on target as it had not been placed there.  Always double check target files :)